# Cold and hot water lines crossover and condensation

Tags: plumbing

I'm in the process of upgrading my existing washer box to a model with an automatic shutoff feature. In the meantime, I want to correct an initial plumbing configuration mistake during construction: the cold water is being connected to the hot water valve via a red pipe and vice versa. I'm considering rectifying this error to adhere to standard conventions, but I'm concerned that doing so will lead to an inevitable crossover between the cold and hot water lines and causing condensation.

I think I would have enough clearance for insulating one of the pipes with black foam. Given this scenario, are there any other better measures can I correct this plumbing error? if not, does it matter which pipe I insulate?

[image: Current setup]

[image: Switch the order]

Comment: Why do you think there will be condensation if they touch?  If insulating either of them, insulate the cold, as that's where condensation will occur, if it occurs at all.  But just having the two PEX pipes touching won't cause any problems at all, and certainly not any condensation differences than if they weren't in contact with each other.